# Equivalent of C programming syntax "#define" in Julia language

Tags: c, julia, compile-time-constant

In the C Programming Language, the `#define` directive allows the definition of macros within the source code. These macro definitions allow constant values to be declared for use throughout the code.

Macro definitions are not variables and cannot be changed by the program code like variables. We generally use this syntax when creating constants that represent numbers, strings or expressions.
like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAME "Jack"
#define AGE 10

int main()
{
   printf("%s is over %d years old.\n", NAME, AGE);
   return 0;
}
```

The beauty is that if I have multiple functions in my code I don't need to *input* the constant variable into every function, and the compiler simply replaces the defined expression with proceeding value.

Now my question is: *Is there any equivalent command in Julia programming for this?*

for example

```
density = 1 # somehow a defined variabe.
function bar(g)
    t =  density +g
end
function foo()
     r = dencity + 2
end 

main()
   g = 10;
   foo()
   bar(g)
end
```

Comment: There is no exact equivalent but you can use `const` instead,

Comment: [Named constants](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Constants-1)? [Macros](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#man-macros-1)?

Comment: do I need to use the variable in the function input arguments every time?

Comment: No, the functions have access to (const) variables in global scope

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Thank you.

Comment: @Some programmer dude thank you. you posted useful links.

Comment: And all I needed was a very quick search through the documentation. I've *never* programmed in Julia. I don't want to sound condescending but please try to do it first yourself next time.

Comment: Why do you expect most of C features to be available mutans mutandis in Julia?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Im not an English native so I didnt understand `mutans mutandis`. By the way, If Ive understood your question, my answer is "Because I believe that Julia is a strong language".I am currently working in a research center. I have codes from the previous researchers that is written in C\C++, Fortran or Matlab and I need to translate them into Julia If I can find the equivalent of each instruction I don't need to reinvent a new algorithm So it is much more easier for me and my colleagues to understand what is happening.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I fined the meaning of mutans mutandis. :))

Comment: Sorry, meant [mutatis mutandis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis) (latin phrase usable in English & French)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* emulate the C `#define` behavior with a `macro` in Julia.

```
macro NAME()
    return :("Jack")
end

macro AGE()
    return :(10)
end
```

In the Julia REPL, typing `@NAME` will return `"Jack"`.

```
julia> @NAME
"Jack"

julia> @AGE
10
```

Remember to enclose the macro call in parentheses for safety, e.g.,

```
julia> println("Hello ", (@NAME))
Hello Jack

julia> println(@NAME * " is " * repr(@AGE) * " years old")
ERROR: syntax: "*" is not a unary operator

julia> println((@NAME) * " is " * repr(@AGE) * " years old")
Jack is 10 years old
```

---

But is this really necessary? The idiomatic way in Julia is to define global `const` variables. Although the documentation discourages the use of global variable for performance reasons, a macro like this does not help you on performance, and you can tell it from the LLVM code.

```
macro NAME()
    return :("Jack")
end

const name = "Jack"

function f_hello_global()
    println("Hello ", name)
end

function f_hello_macro()
    println("Hello ", (@NAME))
end
```

For trivial functions like these, you'll find that the LLVM codes look exactly the same (too long; not shown here).

```
julia> @code_llvm f_hello_global()
. . . 

julia> @code_llvm f_hello_macro()
. . .
```

---

Edit: By the way, I would argue that if you have a *need* to use the global variable, then use it. The argument made in the Julia documentation (current stable version: 0.6.2) is that it may slow down the performance sometimes. However, imagine if a constant is used in 100 functions spread in 20 modules, would you prefer to write the same line of code 100 times and painstakingly check if the numbers are consistent across modules, or would you define it once and use it in all places? I'd think that the proper use of global constants makes the code clean and easy to maintain, and this concern often prevails over a small gain in performance.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to all who answered me.
I found that `global` and `const` keywords will help me do such things but there are some performance restriction on using them i.e. type definition and type recognition of global variables by Julia.
Although you can use `const` and `global` to make a variable visible in the global scope, it is not recommended in Julia documentations.